# How do I make Check Constraints run before statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running into a problem where my check constraints are correctly stopping commands from executing but my Identity column value increases. I guess this is because the check occurs after the statement runs and the transaction gets rolled back due to the check failing. This leaves the identity value incremented by 1.

Is there a way to run the constraint check before the SQL statement gets executed?

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    Name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Type-1'),('Type-2'),('Type-55'),('Type-009')

--Add a check constraint so nobody can edit this without doing serious work
ALTER TABLE TestTable WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CHECK_TestTable_READONLY] CHECK(1=0)


--This fails with the constraint as expected
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('This will Fail')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('This will again....')


--Check the Id, it was incremented...
SELECT (IDENT_CURRENT( 'TestTable' )  ) As CurrentIdentity
```

Comment: The question is why do you care that the identity gets incremented? An identity is a value that tracks the number of attempted inserts. Identity values will have gaps. It is totally natural an expected. If you need a perfectly consistent set of running numbers then you are either too reliant on the identity and should use something else or you are being entirely too pedantic about keeping things clean and tidy.

Comment: Check before Insert? But holes in the identity columns are irrelevant and expected so dont worry about it.

Comment: pedantic. I was about to use that earlier! Identity is just a number to uniquely identify a record.  GAPS shouldn't matter.  If use use a GUID do you think about gaps? NO! why because you never really know what GUID you'll get next!

Comment: The gaps in the identity values aren't problematic and its more of an annoyance than anything else. So your 'pedantic' comments may be quite accurate. What I currently do is reset the ID every time i need to add a record to the table, which is extremely rare.

Comment: If Identity values are important to you, let's hope you don't have SQL Server 2012, where restarting the service can cause your Identity values to jump by 10000 (depending on the datatype involved). If you manually reset the ID every time you add a record, why have it as an Identity column at all? Why not just have an INT NOT NULL that you set yourself when inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had to do the same thing in the past I created a trigger that just threw an exception on insert and delete. this has several advantages, most importantly is that it prevents updates and deletes and you could give a custom exception message explaining what you did there and why, its an extremely bad habit to just put illogical constraints and hope that 3 months from now people would understand whats going on there and know they should ask you about it. It also prevents the Id counter from being incremented if its that important. If it is important, I would also not use auto increment and just set the ID number manually, since even if you are using these triggers you could always have an accidental syntax error or any other error after you disabled them and tried to add a value.

```
create trigger PreventChanges
on TestTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
as
begin
  throw 51000, 'DO NOT change anything in that table unless you really have to! in order to do so pleasae talk to GER (or just disable and reenable this trigger)',1
and
```

Comment: This idea is a nice alternative to using the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're intending to use the identity column for something it's not meant for.  But to answer your question, could you not just manually code up some SQL Server IF statements to test your data before the insert happens (perhaps in a stored procedure)?  I wouldn't know how to make this dynamic to 'fit all constraints on any table', but the process would do what you want - prevent the INSERT from firing.  Though, if your constraints change, then you would have to change the procedure too.

e.g.,

```
IF 1 = 0 -- or use any of your constraints here...
    BEGIN
        -- nest more IFs if you have multiple check-constraints...
        INSERT INTO TestTable 
        VALUES ('This will not increase your identity number since 1 does not equal 0')
    END
```